# PHP page works once

Tags: php

The code works once but then it will not load the customer_login.php page again. It gives HTTp 404 Not Found error when I try for a second time.  Between the time it was working and got the error, I did not change anything.

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"]))
    {
        header("location: ./admin/website/".$websitelocation."/index.html");
        exit();
    }
     ?>
     <?php
if(isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); 
        $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); 

        include "./scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT UsersID, Active, Website_Location  FROM users WHERE       User_Name='$manager' AND Password='$password' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

        $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        echo $existCount;

        if ($existCount == 1) 
                {
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                        { 
                            $id = $row["UsersID"];
                            $active = $row["Active"];
                            $websitelocation = $row["Website_Location"];                            
                        }
                    if($active == 'Yes')
                    {   
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                        $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
                        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;

                        header("location: ./admin/website/".$websitelocation."/index.html");

                        exit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You are not authorized to login!!!!');</script> ";

                        echo "click here to go back to <a href='admin_login.php'>login page</a>. <br><br>"; 
                        echo "click here to go to <a href='../customer_login.php'>customer login</a>. <br><br>";
                        echo "click here to go to <a href='../index.php'>JE Designs LLC main page</a>. <br><br>";                               

                        exit();
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The information you have entered is not correct, please try again.');</script> ";

                    echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Go back to login page.</a>"; 


                    exit();
                }

    }
     ?>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>User Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
    <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
    <div id="pageContent"><br />
<div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
  <h2>Log in to view website.</h2>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="
  <?php 
    if(isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"]))
        {
            echo "./admin/website/".$websitelocation."/index.html"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "customer_login.php";
        }
  ?> " >
    User Name:<br />
      <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
   <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

     <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />

  </form>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
<?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it redirecting to a page that doesn't exist?

Comment: The redirection URL should be wrong. Try to print it before sending the `Location` header.

Comment: What is the value of $websitelocation in $_SESSION["manager"] block at the top? in the redirect at the bottom of the page (after the login check) you set it to  $websitelocation = $row["Website_Location"]; but that value will be lost when the page is re-loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are already logged in, you redirect to `./admin/website/$websitelocation/index.html`. But where does the variable `$websitelocation` come from? It does not help if you set this variable in the login script! So you will be redirected to `./admin/website//index.html`, and this gives you the 404.

BTW: Don't use relative redirections, it is best practice to include the hostname in the `Location` header, because that is more widely supported.

Comment: Would this keep the customer_login.php from coming up?  When I click on the link fromt he index page it says it could not find the page.  I looked at the file paths all they are correct.

Comment: The redirect prevents the customer_login.php from being showed to the user if he is logged in, because he will be redirected to somewhere else. But when you get the message, that the page was not found, I strongly believe that this refers to the redirected page, not to the customer_login.php. Just look where you were redirected to and find out if this file really exists.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the second time you're loading the page, `$_SESSION["manager"]` is set, and the URL it then redirects to is wrong and thus gives a 404.

My second guess is, that `$websitelocation` isn't defined when you try to do the redirect. If you want it to persist for as long as the `manager` session variable, store it in `$_SESSION['websitelocation']` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Make a include file with Constants of your directory then include it in your scripts. this should save you the headache of defining directories properly all the time http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php